# Difference between defineProps<({})>() and defineProps({ }) syntax?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Actually, I read someone code and they define props using  `defineProps<({})>()` syntax and I research about it and didn't find anything which helps me to understand about this syntax.

**How I Define Props**

```
defineProps({
 
})
```

**How other developer define props**

```
defineProps<({
 
})>()
```

I want to know what's the difference between both syntax.

Thanks in Advance

I actually don't know about two different syntax of defining props in Vue 3 script setup. So, I've tried to ask a question so that I can understand about both syntaxes.

Comment: <here you place a type>, while (here you place a value)

Comment: One is for JS, other for TS. https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html

Comment: Okay! I understand the part where we place a type but the I still confuse about the value part I mean which value we put. Can you share some code snippet so I can fully understand.

Comment: @WaleedTariq first of all you need to know which one you want to use, JS or TS

Comment: @ericmp Thanks for your Valuable comment. Now I understand what's going on.

Comment: @WaleedTariq why my question has been unaccepted?

Comment: @ericmp Sorry man, I thought I can accept multiple answer at the same time, lol

Comment: @WaleedTariq this is funny, some years ago happened the same to me and the person asked me why i unaccepted their answer too xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the language (`Javascript` / `TypeScript`).

`JS` (weakly typed):

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  foo: String,
  bar: Number
})
</script>
```

`TS` (strongly typed):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}>()
</script>
```

So in `TypeScript` you need to tell the type, while in `JavaScript` you don't.

Related docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html

Answer (score 2):

Inside the angular brackets, you specify the generic type of the `props` you receive in your component ( this syntax is valid on typescript not javascript )

For example, you receive `age` and `name` props.

With javascript

```
defineProps({
  age: number,
  name: string,
})
```

With typescript, you can do the same as javascript, but if there are type mismatches you will get a warning on the runtime, [or define types via generics where you get errors in compile time](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props)

```
const props = defineProps<{
  age: number,
  name: string
}>()
```